# VirtualBox on MacBook Air M1

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, apple-m1

I see the following 2 errors when running Oracle VirtualBox:
[image]

I have no allow button in security&privacy and enabling SIP did not work for me.
How can I solve this problem? Can incompatibility with M1 be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox is an x86 virtualization hypervisor.  It only runs on an x86 platform .  See https://www.virtualbox.org

While Rosetta 2 will run many x86 apps very well on an M1 Mac, virtualization products are not supported per this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment)

So yes, M1 compatibility is probably the reason for the errors.

Comment: Does VirtualBox work with MacBook Pro i7 Big Sur?